# The best way to develop excel addin

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I want to develop an application for Excel 2016.
I have seen that there are two ways to develop:
- Using VSTO.
- Using "App for Office"

I'm lost and I need your help. What is the best way to develop an application/addin for Excel?

Thaks

Comment: I personally have used the [Add-In Express libraries](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) to great success - they're commercial and cost some money, but that's an amount of money very well spent since it saves you a lot of grief and messy code!

Comment: Add-in Express allows to build COM add-ins (like VSTO does). But it doesn't provide anything for Office Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you need to achieve...

The main differences are listed below:

1. Office Apps have a limited set of API while COM add-ins provide rich set of properties and methods available for developers.
2. COM add-ins are support by all Office versions while Office Apps can work only in Office 2013 and 2016. Note, COM add-ins can be loaded only by the desktop editions of Office.
3. A rich UI extensibility model is available for COM add-ins. Office Apps supports only Ribbon commands.
4. Deployment scenarious. Office Apps can be installed via Office Store. You need to develop an installer for COM add-ins. See [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) for more information.

Also you may find the [Choosing an Excel technology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749815.aspx) article helpful.